# SBML .xml file failure to load in SBMLR (Bioconductor)

Tags: r, xml, bioconductor, sbml

I have downloaded the file BIOMD0000000175.xml from here https://www.ebi.ac.uk/biomodels-main/BIOMD0000000175. I try to load it into SBMLR with

```
library(SBMLR)
mapk <- readSBML("BIOMD0000000175.xml")
> summary(mapk)
Error in x$law(S0[c(x$reactants, x$modifiers)], x$parameters) : 
object 'membrane' not found
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should specify that it's from Bioconductor

Comment: tried it, looks like a bug in the pkg, i'd report to the authors http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SBMLR.html

Comment: Although this is not an answer to the question of why the OP's problem exists in SBMLR, I wanted to mention that there is a second R interface for SBML.  It is part of libSBML.  You can find instructions for installing the libSBML R interface at http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML/Downloading_libSBML#If_you_use_R.  I have not tried it with this specific model, but it should work.  (Full disclosure: I'm a developer of SBML and libSBML.)